# Writing a log macro in Clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

I am attempting problem 4 in [this teaching text on
Clojure](https://aphyr.com/posts/305-clojure-from-the-ground-up-macros)
and am confused by the results of my program:

```
(def logging-enabled true)
(defmacro log
  "uses a var, logging-enabled, to determine whether or not to print an expression to the console at compile time. If logging-enabled is false, (log :hi) should macroexpand to nil. If logging-enabled is true, (log :hi) should macroexpand to (prn :hi)."
  [expr]
  (if logging-enabled
    `(prn ~expr)
    nil
    ))
```

When I attempt to test my program, evaluating each of the forms below

```
(let [logging-enabled true]
  (log "hi there"))

(let [logging-enabled false]
  (log "hi there"))

(let [logging-enabled true]
  (macroexpand (log "hi there")))
```

leads to the REPL replying with the exact same response:

```
user=> 
"hi there"
nil
user=>
```

The `hi there` implies that the macro returned the `true` branch of
its `if` form. The `nil` would be return value from the enclosing
`let` form.

But the question is: why would `"hi there"` be printed when
`logging-enabled` has been scoped to `false` in my second test form
above?

And also: Why is `macroexpand` not expanding my macro but simply doing
the same thing as the two test forms above it?

Answer (score 3):

Macros are expanded at compile-time so when your macro runs `logging-enabled` refers to the var `logging-enabled`, not the `logging-enabled` bound by the enclosing let. You need to include the `if` condition in the returned form and quote it to prevent the name from being resolved:

```
(defmacro log
  [expr]
  `(if ~'logging-enabled
     (prn ~expr)))
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused by `~'logging-enabled` ... how is this different from `~logging-enabled` ?

Comment: Also note: `macroexpand` does not seem to expand even your new macro - it seems to evaluate it.

Comment: @TerrenceBrannon - How are you calling `macroexpand`? `(macroexpand '(log "message")) => (if logging-enabled (clojure.core/prn "message"))` for me. You need to quote `logging-enabled` to prevent it being resolved to the `your-ns/logging-enabled` var since you want to bind it dynamically.

Comment: You should not use `~'` with `logging-enabled` here.  It will expand to an unqualified symbol, but you really want it to expand to a qualified symbol.

Comment: @Lee - I dont have my console to review the history, but based on these comments, I believe I was forgetting the `quote` in front of the expression I was using.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the text for problem 4 (emphasis added):

> Write a macro `log` which uses a var, `logging-enabled`, to *determine whether or not to print an expression to the console **at compile time***. If `logging-enabled` is false, `(log :hi)` should macroexpand to `nil`. If `logging-enabled` is true, `(log :hi)` should macroexpand to `(prn :hi)`. Why would you want to do this check during compilation, instead of when running the program? What might you lose?

Your macro conforms to this specification.  We can confirm this with the following experiments:

```
;; With logging-enabled false
(def logging-enabled false)

(macroexpand '(log :hi))
;;=> nil

;; With logging-enabled true
(def logging-enabled true)

(macroexpand '(log :hi))
;;=> (clojure.core/prn :hi)
```

Note what we're passing to `macroexpand`:  `'(log :hi)`.  `'` is a reader shortcut for [`quote`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote).  So this is equivalent to `(quote (log :hi))`:

```
(read-string "'(log :hi)")
;;=> (quote (log :hi))
```

This is important, because `macroexpand` is a function, so its argument is evaluated before `macroexpand` is called.

> What might you lose?

I think this is a good example of doing too much at compile time.  By performing the check at compile time, you save a little bit of time by not performing the check at runtime.  **But**, you lose the ability to turn logging on and off dynamically -- whatever `logging-enabled` was set to when a particular `log` form was `macroexpand`ed determines whether that form will print a message or not.

It would be more practical if this check is performed at runtime.  Then we can enabled and disable logging at runtime.

While we're at it, we may as well make `logging-enabled` a [dynamic var](http://www.peterfessel.com/2014/11/understanding-the-difference-between-lexical-and-dynamic-scope-in-clojure/).  That way, we can strategically enable / disable logging within specific dynamic scopes.

```
(def ^:dynamic *logging-enabled* false)
```

By convention, dynamic vars have their names augmented with `*`s.  This isn't a requirement, but it does serve as a reminder that the var is dynamic.

Now, we can define `log` as:

```
(defmacro log [expr]
  `(when *logging-enabled*
     (prn ~expr)))
```

`` ` `` indicates [quasi-/syntax-quotation](http://clojure.org/reference/reader#syntax-quote).  Basically, it's similar to `quote`, except you can escape the quotation using `~`.

With this definition of `log`, there is a minute amount of runtime overhead for evaluating a `log` form -- lookup of the (dynamic) value of `*logging-enabled*`, and checking the resulting value.  But, if `*logging-enabled*` is `false`, that's it -- we don't evaluate the expression passed to `log`, and we don't print anything to the console.  So the runtime overhead is minimal.

We can use this new version of `log` like this:

```
;; Root value for *logging-enabled* is false
(log :hi)
;;=> nil

;; dynamically bind *logging-enabled* to true
(binding [*logging-enabled* true]
  (log :hi))
;; Prints ":hi"
```

Comment: I would amend "except you can escape the quotation using ~." by also mentioning that you can also escape the quotation with `~@`.